# applying functions over rows

Tags: r, function, row, multiple-columns

I am using the R programming language. I am interested in seeing if it is possible to apply a function over the whole row.

for instance, suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
var_1 <- rnorm(10000,1,4)
var_2<-rnorm(10000,10,5)
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
response_variable <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )


#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, response_variable)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$response_variable = as.factor(f$response_variable)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)
```

(in base R) Is it possible to write a command : "select rows where the value of "var_1" and "var_2" are both greater than 2? (i.e. select rows where the minimum value in that row is greater than 2). I could individually write an "if else" statement, but suppose there are many columns - is it possible to do this without specifying every column?

The same way - is it possible to apply a function on multiple columns at the same time?

Suppose there is the following function:

```
ihs <- function(x) {
    y <- log(x + sqrt(x ^ 2 + 1))
    return(y)
}
```

I could write:

```
f$var_1 = ihs(f$var_1)
f$var_2 = ihs(f$var_2)
```

But is there a quicker way (when there are more columns) to apply the function "ihs" on the whole table (where applicable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, this can be done with `lapply` after subsetting the columns of interest ('nm1')

```
nm1 <- grep('^var_\\d+$', names(f), value = TRUE)
f[nm1] <- lapply(f[nm1], ihs)
```

---

If the function needs to be applied based on `type` i.e. numeric columns and also to apply the function only if the `min` value is greater than 2

```
i1 <- sapply(f, is.numeric)
i2 <- do.call(pmin, f[i1]) > 2
```

or this can be done using `rowSums` as well

```
i2 <- rowSums(f[i1] >2) == length(i1)
f[i2, i1] <- lapply(f[i2, i1], ihs)
```

---

Or if we want to use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
f <- f %>%
         mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ihs))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! but is there a way for the computer to automatically recognize, only to apply the "ihs" function only on numeric/ variables?

Comment: is it possible to do the first part of the question? keep row, if minimum value in that row is greater than 2?

Comment: @stats555 DO you want to apply the function only if the columns are all greater than 2?

Comment: thank you for your reply. yes, if for a given row, all numeric columns are greater than 2

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried the code: i1 <- sapply(f, is.numeric)
i2 <- do.call(pmin, f[i1]) > 2 .... but it gives me a vector of TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE .... is there a way to directly keep only those rows that meet the condition?

Comment: @stats555 Yes, the TRUE values are the ones that can be used as row index for subsetting the rows, so, we use `f[i2, i1]` i.e. row/column indexing

Answer (score 1):

To select rows where `var1` and `var2` are greater than 2 you can do :

```
subset(f, var_1 > 2 & var_2 > 2)
```

The same code can be applied in `dplyr::filter`

```
dplyr::filter(f, var_1 > 2 & var_2 > 2)
```